# Изменить содержимое div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function draw(a, b) {

    $('body').append('<div id = container2 class = container>');

    $('#container2').append('<div id = a'+' class = class1><p>' + a.text + '</p></div>');
    $('#container2').append('<div id = b'+' class = class1><p>' + b.text + '</p></div>');

}

function reDraw(a, b) {

    $('#a').attr('<p>' + a.text + '</p></div>');
    $('#b').attr('<p>' + b.text + '</p></div>');

}
```

Функция `draw` работает нормально, `reDraw` - совсем не работает.

Как отобразить уже измененный текст (a.text) в функции `reDraw`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function reDraw(a, b) {
    $('#a').text(a.text);
    $('#b').text(b.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не работает потому что `<p>` это не атрибут. Если нужно вставлять часть html кода то вместо `.attr()` воспользуйтесь `.html()` и вместо `'</p></div>'`будет `'</p>'`. Если просто нужно вставить текст то тогда `.text()`